# Applying patch to subprocess library

Tags: python, subprocess, patch

I am trying to apply patch to subprocess library. Using following script and get the error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'module' and 'module'

```
os.chdir("C:/Users/Downloads")
import patch
patch -subprocess < issue_28168_03.patch
```

I downloaded the patch from https://bugs.python.org/issue28168

Need help with the error.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/patch/

Answer (score 0):

I was actually trying to apply the patch to fix issues with Uninterruptible subprocess when opening an exe file. I fixed it using following script.

```
import subprocess
import time

binary_path = 'path/file.exe'
args = 'arguments' # arbitrary

call_str = '{} {}'.format(binary_path, args)

proc = subprocess.Popen(call_str)
```